# API build fails in WSO2 API Microgateway 3.1.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am new to WSO2 microgateway and was following the steps given in the documentation : "https://docs.wso2.com/display/MG310/Quick+Start+Guide+-+Binary" for exposing the Petstore service via microgateway.

I was able to initialize the API using the swagger file as given in the steps. The Petstore project is also created under the project directory. But when i try to build the project as given in Step 1.2, it fails with an error as shown below. Need suggestions to resolve this issue.

[image]

In the ballerina-internal.log file, i get the below error.

[2020-07-16 21:13:19,009] SEVERE {b7a.log.crash} - Array index out of range: 0
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 0
at org.ballerinalang.nativeimpl.jvm.interop.JMethodResolver.validateArgumentTypes(JMethodResolver.java:194)
at org.ballerinalang.nativeimpl.jvm.interop.JMethodResolver.validateMethodSignature(JMethodResolver.java:148)
at org.ballerinalang.nativeimpl.jvm.interop.JMethodResolver.resolve(JMethodResolver.java:107)
at org.ballerinalang.nativeimpl.jvm.interop.JInteropMethodValidator.resolveJMethod(JInteropMethodValidator.java:74)
at org.ballerinalang.nativeimpl.jvm.interop.JInteropMethodValidator.validateAndGetJMethod(JInteropMethodValidator.java:61)
at ballerina.jvm.$value$InteropValidator.validateAndGetJMethod(interop.bal:90)
at ballerina.jvm.$value$InteropValidator.call(interop.bal)
at ballerina.compiler_backend_jvm.interop.interop_method_gen.createJMethodWrapper(interop/interop_method_gen.bal:136)
at ballerina.compiler_backend_jvm.interop.interop_method_gen.createJInteropFunctionWrapper(interop/interop_method_gen.bal:128)
at ballerina.compiler_backend_jvm.interop.external_method_gen.createExternalFunctionWrapper(interop/external_method_gen.bal:180)
at ballerina.compiler_backend_jvm.jvm_package_gen.generateClassNameMappings(jvm_package_gen.bal:477)
at ballerina.compiler_backend_jvm.jvm_package_gen.generatePackage(jvm_package_gen.bal:149)
at ballerina.compiler_backend_jvm.jvm_package_gen.generateDependencyList(jvm_package_gen.bal:120)
at ballerina.compiler_backend_jvm.jvm_package_gen.generatePackage(jvm_package_gen.bal:142)
at ballerina.compiler_backend_jvm.jvm_package_gen.generateDependencyList(jvm_package_gen.bal:120)
at ballerina.compiler_backend_jvm.jvm_package_gen.generatePackage(jvm_package_gen.bal:142)
at ballerina.compiler_backend_jvm.jvm_package_gen.generateDependencyList(jvm_package_gen.bal:120)
at ballerina.compiler_backend_jvm.jvm_package_gen.generatePackage(jvm_package_gen.bal:142)
at ballerina.compiler_backend_jvm.jvm_package_gen.generateDependencyList(jvm_package_gen.bal:120)
at ballerina.compiler_backend_jvm.jvm_package_gen.generatePackage(jvm_package_gen.bal:142)
at ballerina.compiler_backend_jvm.main.generateJarBinary(main.bal:86)
at ballerina.compiler_backend_jvm.main.main(main.bal:60)
at ballerina.compiler_backend_jvm.___init.$lambda$main$(compiler_backend_jvm)
at ballerina.compiler_backend_jvm.___init$$Lambda$11.000000001107AEE0.apply(Unknown Source)
at org.ballerinalang.jvm.scheduling.SchedulerItem.execute(Scheduler.java:426)
at org.ballerinalang.jvm.scheduling.Scheduler.run(Scheduler.java:218)
at org.ballerinalang.jvm.scheduling.Scheduler.runSafely(Scheduler.java:191)
at org.ballerinalang.jvm.scheduling.Scheduler$$Lambda$6.0000000010F6DAF0.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:813)

Comment: Just to check if this is caused due to selecting the external jdk, Can you remove the java_home env variable from the system and try again.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2283449/praminda, But without java_home, the other components of WSO2 will not work right like APIM. Is there any other way to fix this issue? I am using jdk-8.0.202.08.

Comment: No you just need to temporarily remove the variable and try. My suggestion was just to find what is causing the issue. if we can isolate external jdk is causing the issue then we can find out a way to force mgw to use internal jdk. `SET JAVA_HOME=""` and running the build command should also give us the required result without external jdk.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2283449/praminda, Appreciate your help. It works if i remove java_home as you mentioned. What could be a permanent solution for this? I have installed the binary distribution of the product and using jdk-8.0.202.08 along with it. Should i try with the product installer instead whcih comes with internal jdk?

Comment: Added an answer with with bit more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the responses in the comments it looks like the external jdk is not fully compatible with mgw. Not sure on the exact reason though. Here is a bit more background on what going on during the build command and a possible workaround to force mgw use internal jdk.

All mgw distributions (toolkit/runtime) including the binary distribution, contains a jdk internally which is fully compatible with the ballerina version used in the mgw. However during the execution of mgw toolkit command it checks for externally installed jdks (by looking at JAVA_HOME variable) and pick it as the jdk if a compatible version is found in the system. Otherwise it will use the internal jdk.

So to avoid mgw from picking up external jdk, we should set JAVA_HOME variable to "" or invalid location. To do that open `micro-gw.bat` (assume you are on windows) file in the `<TOOLKIT_HOME>/bin` directory and around line 55 after `SET HOME_CACHE=%MICROGW_HOME%\lib\gateway-balo` add `SET JAVA_HOME=` as command. After the change code block around above line will look like below.

```
.
.
.
SET PATH=%BALLERINA_HOME%\bin\;%PATH%
SET JAVA_PATH=%MICROGW_HOME%\lib\jdk8u202-b08-jre
SET HOME_CACHE=%MICROGW_HOME%\lib\gateway-balo

REM ******* Below is the line we added to reset the JAVA_HOME *******
SET JAVA_HOME=

REM Check JAVA availability
if EXIST "%JAVA_HOME%" (
    ECHO JAVA_HOME: %JAVA_HOME%
.
.
.
```

Save the file and try the `build` command again. It should work.

Comment: Thanks Praminda https://stackoverflow.com/users/2283449/praminda for the detailed solution. It has worked after following the steps mentioned above and build was successful.

Comment: Great to hear it. Please accept the answer if it helped. It will help other users to notice the right answer if they come across the same issue :)